# Webpack: Order of execution of plugins and minification in production mode

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I am new to webpack and I have the following problem. In production mode I need to replace some strings in my .js file. However, it seems that minification is executed before any other plugins and this causes my replacement not to work.

My webpack version is 4.17.1

What I have currently in my config file is:

```
const ReplaceInFileWebpackPlugin = require('replace-in-file-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require( 'uglifyjs-webpack-plugin' );

module.exports = {
mode: 'production',
entry: './main.js',
output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './minified.js',
},
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin(
        {
            cache: false,
            parallel: false,
            uglifyOptions: {
                compress: false,
                ecma: 6,
                mangle: false,
                keep_classnames: false,
                keep_fnames: false
            },
            sourceMap: true
        })
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new ReplaceInFileWebpackPlugin([{
        dir: __dirname,
        files: ['./main.js'],
        rules: [{
            search: /my_expression/ig,
            replace: 'replacement'
        }]
    }])
]
};
```

Comment: which hook replacefilewebpackplugin is tapping to?

Comment: I am not sure, how can i check? I have no other settings than these

Comment: Replace plugin runs when the application is done, uglify when it is compiling. That is the order.

Comment: I see, is there any way I can first run the plugin (or some other alternative) and then compile and minify

Comment: No idea actually...

Comment: Thanks! You gave me some light!

Comment: this could help you: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/140 (but didn't work for me though.)